# How to convert array to dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, c#-6.0

How to convert below fieldList array to dictionary as `Dictionary<string,column> (i.e. Dictionary of name property of column class as key and value property of dictionary as column object)`.

```
public class columninfo
{
 public string name {get;set;}
 public column[] fieldList {get;set;}
}

public class column
{
  public string name {get;set;}
  public string fieldname {get;set}
  public string format {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a linq lambda for this.

```
column[] columns = getColumninfo();
columns.ToDictionary(x => x.name, y => y);
```

By adding `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` you can ensure that the column name lookup is case insensitive.

```
columns.ToDictionary(x => x.name, y => y, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
fieldList.ToDictionary(c=>c.name, c=>c);
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter you're taking about the name of the parent class, he asked about the array inside